# Localizar uma inforção em um json usanndo node.js no dialogflow

Tags: node.js, google, google-sheets

Estou tentando localizar uma informação a partir de uma entrada no dialogflow em um json, mas ele só funciona quando eu tento localizar a primeira linha, o resto não consigo.

```
if (intentName == "AUTORIZADO"){  
      var DOC = req.body.queryResult.parameters['DOC']
      return axios.get("LINK").then(resp=> {
        resp.data.map(resp=>{
            if(resp.DOC==DOC){
              res.json({"fulfillmentText":"DOC:"+resp.VALUE})}
            
            else {res.json({"fulfillmentText": "TEXT."})}
            
        })
      })

    }
```

Comment: Importante você [editar sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/542728/70) e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada fornecendo um [mcve] do problema no lugar do código atual. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Para evitar duplicação de informação, os comentários foram bloqueados nesta postagem aqui, mas podem ser feitos no espaço apropriado da [pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/542728/70).